# Changing color of image according to ranges?

Tags: colors, scheme

I'm trying to make a procedure that uses image-map to change the color of a image according to a range. Like this:

```
If the sum of the RGB channels for one pixel = 0 to 181 then the color would be (0 51 76)
If the sum = 182 to 363 then the color would be (217 26 33)
If the sum = 364 to 545 then the color would be (112 150 158)
If the sum = 546 to 765 then the color would be (252 227 166)
```

Now, here's what I have so far:

```
(define (sum p)
  (image-map
   (lambda (c)
    (+ (color-ref c 'red) (color-ref c 'green) (color-ref c 'blue)))
   p))

(define color-range
  (lambda (c)
    (cond
      [(< (sum c) 181) (color 0 51 76)]
      [(and (>= (sum c) 182) (<= (sum c) 363)) (color 217 26 33)]
      [(and (>= (sum c) 364) (<= (sum c) 545)) (color 112 150 158)]
      [(and (>= (sum c) 546) (<= (sum c) 765)) (color 252 227 166)])))
```

So, I made a helper function to calculate the sum of each pixel. When I run color-range, I get an error saying that:

Exception in image-map: #[color 255 255 255] is not the correct type, expected image

Help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the expected input for `sum`, a pixel or an image? if it's a pixel, why traverse it using `image-map`? if it's an image, why adding all the color components of all its pixels and setting *that* as a new pixel?

I believe this is closer to what you intended (I can't tell for sure with just the snippet of code currently in the question); also notice that I fixed a couple of bugs in `color-range`:

```
(define sum
  (lambda (c)
    (+ (color-ref c 'red)
       (color-ref c 'green)
       (color-ref c 'blue))))

(define color-range
  (lambda (c)
    (cond
      [(<= 0   (sum c) 181) (color 0 51 76)]
      [(<= 182 (sum c) 363) (color 217 26 33)]
      [(<= 364 (sum c) 545) (color 112 150 158)]
      [else                 (color 252 227 166)])))

(define change-colors
  (lambda (image)
    (image-map (lambda (pixel)
                 (color-range pixel))
               image)))
```

Of course, the above can be further optimized (for example, by removing the multiple calls to `sum`, and passing `color-range` directly to `image-map`, etc.) but first, let's make sure that the above works and that you understand what it's doing.

Comment: I think I'm trying to get a pixel for sum and that's what your did, right? So, if I'm looking a pixel, I shouldn't use image-map because that returns an image, right?

Comment: That's right, and don't forget to test each helper procedure individually before incorporating them in the main procedure that implements the solution

Answer (score 0):

You are conflating images and colors (you are calling `sum` with a color but `sum` expects an image, it seems).  Be more explicit with your types.  For example:

```
(define (color-intensity c)
  (+ (color-ref c 'red) (color-ref c 'green) (color-ref c 'blue)))

(define (remap-color c)
  (let ((intensity (color-intensity c)))
    (cond [(<=   0 intensity 181) ...]
          [(<= 182 intensity 363) ...]
          ...)))

(define (remap-image i)
  (image-map remap-color i))
```